# Google drive api saving to file

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to save a file by using `google drive api`.

Code that I am using to save file at the moment looks following:

```
 final java.io.File file = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "Json.txt");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            if (file.exists()) {
                final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                final String json = gson.toJson(filesEvent);
                fileWriter.write(json);
                fileWriter.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the part that is supposed to get the file contents:

```
final StringBuilder sb = getStringBuilder(new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator + "Json.txt"));
            File file  = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), File.class);
```

Comment: Hi Przemek, you might want to add errors and more details to your question as it is hard to make out what is exact problem that you are experiencing with code above. Thanks.

Comment: When i do my json from google, like gson.toJson(filesEvent), and then just gson.fromJson(json, FilesEvent.class) i get invalid value for field

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you want to save a text file ('json.txt') to Google Drive and your code applies to Android.

First, you do not indicate what API you decided to use, the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Api or the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro).

Starting with *java.io.File* as an input (your first code block), here are code snippets for both the GDAA and REST Apis.

**GDAA:** (you may consider turning the 'await' methods into callbacks, or you have to wrap it in non-UI thread)

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}

  com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient mGAC;
  ... 
  /**********************************************************************
   * create file/folder in GOODrive
   * @param prnId  parent's ID, (null for root)
   * @param titl  file name
   * @param mime  file mime type
   * @param file  file (with content) to create
   * @return      file id  / null on fail
   */
  DriveId createFile(DriveId prnId, String titl, String mime, File file) {
    DriveId dId = null;
    if (mGAC != null && mGAC.isConnected() && titl != null && mime != null && file != null) {
      DriveFolder pFldr = (prnId == null) ?
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGAC): Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGAC, prnId);
      if (pFldr == null) return null; //----------------->>>

      MetadataChangeSet meta;
      DriveContentsResult r1 = Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGAC).await();
      if (r1 == null || !r1.getStatus().isSuccess()) return null; //-------->>>

      meta = new Builder().setTitle(titl).setMimeType(mime).build();
      DriveFileResult r2 = pFldr.createFile(mGAC, meta, r1.getDriveContents()).await();
      DriveFile dFil = r2 != null && r2.getStatus().isSuccess() ? r2.getDriveFile() : null;
      if (dFil == null) return null; //---------->>>

      r1 = dFil.open(mGAC, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();
      if ((r1 != null) && (r1.getStatus().isSuccess()))  {
        Status stts = fileToCont(r1.getDriveContents(), file).commit(mGAC, meta).await();
        if ((stts != null) && stts.isSuccess()) {
          MetadataResult r3 = dFil.getMetadata(mGAC).await();
          if (r3 != null && r3.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            dId = r3.getMetadata().getDriveId();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return dId;
  }

  DriveContents fileToCont(DriveContents driveContents, File file) {
    OutputStream oos = driveContents.getOutputStream();
    if (oos != null) try {
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
      byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
      int c;
      while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
        oos.write(buf, 0, c);
        oos.flush();
      }
    } catch (Exception e)  { UT.le(e);}
    finally {
      try {
        oos.close();
      } catch (Exception ignore) {
      }
    }
    return driveContents;
  }
```

**REST Api:** (you have to wrap it in non-UI thread)

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'
  compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
  compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
}

  com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGOOSvc;
  ...
  /***************************************************************
   * create file/folder in GOODrive
   * @param prnId  parent's ID, (null or "root") for root
   * @param titl  file name
   * @param mime  file mime type
   * @param file  file (with content) to create
   * @return      file id  / null on fail
   */
  static String createFile(String prnId, String titl, String mime, java.io.File file) {
    String rsId = null;
    if (mGOOSvc != null  && titl != null && mime != null && file != null) try {
      File meta = new File();
      meta.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(prnId == null ? "root" : prnId)));
      meta.setTitle(titl);
      meta.setMimeType(mime);

      File gFl = mGOOSvc.files().insert(meta, new FileContent(mime, file)).execute();
      if (gFl != null)
        rsId = gFl.getId();
    }
    catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException uraIOEx) {
      // handle  uraIOEx;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {  
      if (e instanceof GoogleJsonResponseException) {
        if (404 == ((GoogleJsonResponseException)e).getStatusCode())
          // handle  error;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle  error;
    }
    return rsId;
  }
```

Wider context of these methods can be found [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) and [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) if you care to dig deeper.

Good Luck